# GNOME keyring: prompt for password after screen lock

Tags: ssh, security, gnome-keyring

On my Ubuntu (17.04) desktop, GNOME keyring (GK) aka "Seahorse" has my SSH private key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) loaded in.  The key is protected by a password and GK prompts me for a password to unlock it after logging out of my session (eg: after rebooting my box).

So far so good but in order to improve security, I'd rather get prompts a little more often, eg: after the computer unlocked, which would also catch resuming from sleep/hibernation.  This might help mitigate attacks against a laptop stolen while suspended.

Is there a way to achieve this?  A time-based setting similar to `ssh-add -t <duration>` would also work.

Bonus: I have to say I don't fully understand the relationship between GK and `ssh-agent` (despite trying to parse available documentation).  Considerations on whether using GK in this scenario is a serious security risk also welcome.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve this? A time-based setting similar to `ssh-add -t <duration>` would also work.

No. It is not possible to do that using `gnome-keyring`. It has a `ssh-store`, which picks up the default SSH identities and unlocks them on the first use. There is no way to get them "locked" again on the event of locking screen.

> Bonus: I have to say I don't fully understand the relationship between GK and ssh-agent (despite trying to parse available documentation). Considerations on whether using GK in this scenario is a serious security risk also welcome.

The `gnome-keyring` is just implementing `ssh-agent` interface. The `gnome-keyring` is application written to be secure the same way as the `ssh-agent` is. It has just a limited functionality.